# TYPO3 Change extension builder default extension location path from typo3conf/ext to some other path

Tags: typo3

I use extension builder for creating my extensions in TYPO3 V 6.1.1. The default location where the extensions are stored is in `typo3conf/ext/` folder.

I would like to change this location to some other path, say `/MyExtensions/MyExtName`. From this location I'll give symbolic links to ext/ folder.

The problem is changing the default location of extensions from `typo3conf/ext/` to `/MyExtensions/MyExtName`.

How do I do this ?

**EDIT**

Is it possible to create a directory `MyExtensions` under `typo3conf/ext/` and then `MyExtensions` will contain all my custom-made extensions. It's just that it'd be easy to have extensions organized this way. My custom extensions would be in `typo3conf/ext/MyExtensions/MyExtOne` , `typo3conf/ext/MyExtensions/MyExtTwo` etc...

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. Also do not try to circumvent the default typo3 paths but learn to live with them.

Answer (score 0):

Create/Save the extension and copy&paste the content to the location you want to have them. Then create the symlink back to typo3conf/ext. It doesn't matter where the ExtensionBuilder writes the files when the target points to an other directory.